# Use Auth in construct method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

**Laravel Version:** 5.6.*

**PHP Version:** 7.2.2

**Database Driver & Version:** Mysql 5.0.12

**Description:**

I need return logged user in contruct method

**Steps To Reproduce:**
I need return logged user in contruct method,

```
public function __construct(){

        $this->menu = new Menu();

        $this->menu->getEnabledMenu();

        $this->categories = $this->
        menu::with('children')->
        where('parent_id','=',0)->
        whereIn('id', [8,9,7])->
        orderBy('position', 'asc')->
        get();
    }
```

i tried with $this->user->Auth::user()->id; but this doesn't work

i also tried this

https://laravel-news.com/controller-construct-session-changes-in-laravel-5-3

```
$this->middleware(function ($request, $next){
        $this->user= Auth::user();
        return $next($request);
    });
```

but i I do not know how to access $this->user

please
i need help

sorry for my english

Comment: "but i I do not know how to access $this->user"  Did you added the public property of $user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the `$user` property on your controller like:

```
class MyController {
    // keep a reference to the authenticated user.
    public $user;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next){
            $this->user = Auth::user();
            return $next($request);
        });
    }
    ...
}
```